# jfrog bintray: Fixing wrong group id

Tags: artifactory, bintray

The group ID at https://bintray.com/search?query=downloaderFlow does not match the group ID at https://bintray.com/beta/#/vvasuki/sanskrit-coders-android-repo/downloaderFlow?tab=overview , probably because an earlier version of the package mistakenly used a wrong group ID. How to fix?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Please use the Feeback tab on the UI to report the issue to the Bintray team. We'll take it from there.

---

<sup>I am with [JFrog](http://jfrog.com), the company behind [bintray](/questions/tagged/bintray) and [artifactory](/questions/tagged/artifactory), see [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/402053/jbaruch) for details and links.</sup>